# Program crashes when trying to create and access 2-d vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am trying to create a 2-D vector to represent a square matrix for a homework assignment. Although the program compiles successfully, when I try to run it, the program crashes and no output is returned.

Can someone please explain my mistake to me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
  vector < vector<int> > a;
  a[0][0] = 0;
  a[0][1] = 1;
  cout<<a[0][0]<<a[0][1];
  cout<<a.size();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting to your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, when using vector you have to assign memory for the number of elements you want to store. (Well, using arrays too but that's sort of implicit when creating one statically) You just can't go ahead and say you want to store something in a box when there is no box.

There are two ways I can think of to make space for those elements. One is using the constructor as in:

```
std::vector<int> myVector(100); // This makes room for a 100 elements
```

And using the function for that purpose.

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector.reserve(100); // This makes room for a 100 elements after the declaration
```

So from there, I think you can figure out what's next. You just need to make space for everything.

I personally don't use Vector that much because I was never required to (Had to make my own dynamic lists in school and basically used that as my "Vector" library), but I definitely should use it when needed because it offers a lot of advantages.

Just as a notice, one thing I do know is that you are using the unsafe way of accessing data in your vector. Unsafe because it can't throw any exceptions at you to catch if it happens to do a restricted access.

```
std::vector<int> myVector(10);
myVector.at(0) = 0; // What I mean is that function, you can jut wrap it inside a try-catch to make it safer.
myVector[0] = 0; // Instead of this, of course.
```

Of course, then there are iterators and all that stuff which should be safer, but you can look further on that later.

Answer (score 2):

Add printing statement after variable declaration as following, and run the program. And you might be able to find the answer by yourself.

```
int main()
{
  vector < vector<int> > a;
  cout<<a.size();
  a[0][0] = 0;
  a[0][1] = 1;
  cout<<a[0][0]<<a[0][1];
  cout<<a.size();
}
```

Comment: Running your code and questioner code makes same result at cpp.sh !!

Comment: @m.r226 Well, I think you are missing the results the program produced. Run the program and see the results before it crashes. Keep in mind that this is homework problem and we might want to try OP to think and learn. Programming can be learned by reading books and articles, but most by a series of experiments (e.g., trial and error).

Answer (score 0):

In order to fill values in the std::vector, I prefer to use push_back funtion instead of operator[]. The push_back increases the size of vector by one and also do memory realloaction if needed. Remember this solution is good only whem memory reallocation is not an issue. Reserve memory ahead of push_back is always preferable.